# To select data from multiple records in SQL Server having a common ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, azure-sql-database, left-join

I need to select/concat data from 2 tables in SQL Server I'm using Left Join, but the data is returned as multiple records.

Below are the sample tables

```
Table1
Id Name Age
1  Sk   20
2  Rb   30
```

---

```
Table2
ID Bike Price Table1Id
1  RX   200   1
2  CD   250   1
3  FZ   300   1
4  R1   400   2
```

---

```
The desired output is
ID Name Age Bike1 Price1 Bike2 Price2 Bike3 Price3
1  Sk   20  RX    200    CD    250    FZ    300
2  Rb   30  R1    400    NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL
```

---

A sample format of the query I'm using

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Name, B.Bike, B.Price FROM Table1 A LEFT JOIN Table2 B ON
A.id = B.Table1Id order by A.id
```

The output I'm getting from the above query is

```
ID Name Age Bike Price
1  Sk   20  RX   200
1  Sk   20  CD   250
1  Sk   20  FZ   300
2  Rb   30  R1   400
```

I need the data as one record for a particular ID and not multiple records (As seen in the desired output). Tired using offset, but offset will return only limited result not the entire records.

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Comment: What if there are more than three bikes?

Comment: I know there are max three bikes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the maximum number of bikes per person, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ID, Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnm = 1 THEN Bike END) as bike_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnm = 1 THEN Price END) as price_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnm = 2 THEN Bike END) as bike_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnm = 2 THEN Price END) as price_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnm = 3 THEN Bike END) as bike_3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnm = 3 THEN Price END) as price_3
FROM (SELECT A.ID, A.Name, B.Bike, B.Price,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.id ORDER BY B.Price) as seqnum
      FROM Table1 A LEFT JOIN
           Table2 B 
           ON A.id = B.Table1Id 
     ) ab
GROUP BY ID, Name,
ORDER BY id
```